# $ \int_0^i\!e^z\,\mathrm{d}z $

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function that I need to integrate. I can't figure out how to do so though.

$$ \int_0^i\!e^z\,\mathrm{d}z $$

My intuition is telling me that the answer is $ e^i - 1 = \cos(1) + i\sin(1) - 1 $, but I can't find anything in my book that suggests this is true. The closest thing I have is $ \int_C f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z = F(z(b)) - F(z(a)) $, where $ C = z(t), a \leq t \leq b $ and $ f(z) = F'(z) $. This proposition is only true for a line integral, so I'm not sure if/how it applies to the above. A step in the right direction would be very helpful, or an explanation of the general procedure for doing this type of integration. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Integration in the complex plane must be along a path.  If the function is holomorphic (such as $e^z$), then the integral will not depend on the choice of a path.  You might as well parametrize the segment at constant speed:  $\gamma(t) = it$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: This is line integral. It's just your line goes from $0$ to $i$.

Comment: You might like this article.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrand is an entire function, therefore line integral depends only from starting and ending points. Since points $z_0=0$ and $z_1=1$ lie on the $OY$-axis, you can integrate along the segment $I=\{z\mid z=0+iy,\;\; {0}\leqslant{y} \leqslant{1}\}$, thus $$\int\limits_{0}^{i}{e^z}dz=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{e^{iy}}d(iy)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{d\left(e^{iy}\right)}=\left.e^{iy} \right|_{0}^{1}$$

Comment: $ \mathrm{d}(iy) = i\mathrm{d}y $ does it not? Shouldn't the solution be $ i(cos(1) + isin(1) - 1) $

Comment: By [Euler's formula] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) $e^{iy}=\cos{y}+i\sin{y} $

Comment: The antiderivate of $e^{iy}$ w.r.t. $y$ is $\frac 1 i e^{iy}$, so the $i$ cancels out.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $\frac{d e^z}{dz} =e^z$. Choose $z(t) = it$, and $C$ the line that connects $0$ and $i$. Then $z(0)= 0,z(1) = i$. Thus your integral becomes $$\int_0^i e^z dz = e^z|_{z(0)}^{z(1)} = e^i-e^0 = e^i-1$$

Comment: My problem is I don't understand the justification for your equality.